# How to pass enum class to QML?

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qml

I am on learning to **QML** with **Qt** and get some trouble with passing `enum class` to `qml`.

When I use signal with `int` parameters - it's all right and code work perfectly.

But, **and here the trouble**, if I use signal with some `enum class` parameters I have `undefined` values in qml signal handler. I tried to register `enum class` through `qmlRegisterType` but it's not working. I will be grateful for the help.

Here the code:

**Some** `Helper` **class**

```
class Helper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(Requester)
    Q_ENUMS(JANSWER)

public:

enum class Requester {
    ReqLogin,
    ReqNull,
    ReqSave,
    ReqError,
    ReqUnknown
};

enum class JANSWER {
    OK,
    Complete,
    Error,
    Unknown
};

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<JsonPackWorker>("com.jsonpackworker", 1, 0, "JsonPackWorker");
    qmlRegisterType<Helper>("com.Helper", 1, 0, "Helper");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**JsonPackWorker.h**

```
class JsonPackWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    <...>

signals:    
    <...>
    void sendAnswer(Helper::Requester req, Helper::JANSWER answer);

public slots:
    <...>
};
```

**Somewehere in JsonPackWorker.cpp**

```
emit sendAnswer(Helper::Requester::ReqNull, Helper::JANSWER::OK);
```

**main.qml**

```
<...>
import com.jsonpackworker 1.0
import com.Helper 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow

    // Requests in answers
    property int reqLogin: Helper.ReqLogin

    <...>

    JsonPackWorker {
        id: packWorker
        <...>
        onSendAnswer: {
            // Here I've got undefined undefined if there enum class parameters
            console.log(req + " " + answer)
            switch(req) {
            case reqLogin: loginDial.checkLogin(answer)
                break;
            default:
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *How* is it not working? Do you get build errors? Crashes at run-time? Unexpected results? Something else? Please elaborate. And if you haven't done so yet, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does it work by changing `enum class` to `enum` ?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, I wrote that I've got an undefined values in handler. Code shows `console.log()` where I commented that part with description.

Comment: @coyotte508, if I changes `enum class` to `enum` I should change my signal to `void sendAnswer(int req, int answer);` and it will work perfectly. But it's not interesting way.

Comment: For what it's worth, it works when the enum belongs to the `JsonPackWorker` class itself. As for why it doesn't work when using the enum of another registered class, I can only assume it's a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was in `Helper` class (thanks to Qt community).

```
class Helper {
   ...
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Helper::Requester)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Helper::JANSWER)
```

Comment: For more info read this official doc: [Enumeration Types as Signal and Method Parameters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#enumeration-types-as-signal-and-method-parameters)