# How to pass just an enum class to qml?

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qml

I have a .h file with only enum class.

**somefile.h**

```
enum class Someclass {
a = 0,
b = 3,
// ...
z = 100
};
```

As you can see there are no Q_OBJECT's or Q_GADGET's around. But i want to get access to this class in qml like

```
...
property var someProperty: Someclass.a
...
```

Ofcourse I tried to use something like **anotherclass.h**

```
class Anotherclass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUM (Someclass)
    ...
};
```

or even

```
class Anotherclass : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   typedef Someclass Myclass;
   Q_ENUM (Myclass)
   ...
};
```

with **somewhere.cpp**

```
...
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Anotherclass> ("somepackage", 1, 0, "somepackage is used only for getting enum");
...
```

and this doesn't work. I have no access to somefile.h, but I really want to have this enum in qml. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass enum class to QML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415542/how-to-pass-enum-class-to-qml)

Comment: No it's not. I have different situation, because enum class is not in QObject  class.

Answer (score 0):

just use Q_OBJECT derived class and declare your enum in that class namespace.

```
class SomeClass: public QObject 
{
    Q_OBJECT
    enum SomeEnum {
    a = 0,
    b = 3,
    z = 100
    };
    Q_ENUM(SomeEnum)
};
```

more info [here](https://woboq.com/blog/q_enum.html)

Comment: I can't do like that, because of no access to .h file. Even duplicate of the enum in NewSomeClass will not help me.